# Dont get content in IE xml/jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, internet-explorer

The trouble is that everything works fine on every browser except IE. I get content from xml and I am able to print it, but on IE it gives empty.

After some googling the problem might be width this header("content-type:application/xml;charset=utf-8");
Where am I suppoesed to put that? On the xml file start or?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you paste some code so we know what you are trying?

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript:

```
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open("POST", "http://www.example.com/", true);
  req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Check the JQuery XHR documentation for a similar API.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    'url': '',
    'beforeSend': function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    }
});
```

also try to disable ie cache with php

header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Pragma: no-cache");